# How do I make a table that is based on the sum of other columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help phrasing this question. I am new to MySQL. I bet this question was asked, but I do not know the terminology to ask the right question.

Let's say I have two tables in MySQL. Table 1 is where new data gets inserted. Table 2 should automatically update. The data within Table 2 is a sum of specified columns within each row of table 1.

For example,

```
TABLE 1
| ID |  A |  B |  C |  D |
|----+----+----+----+----|
| 0  | 11 | 10 | 39 | 11 |
| 1  | 32 | 21 | 21 | 12 |
| 2  | 12 | 23 | 24 | 13 |
| 3  | 45 | 35 | 31 | 14 |

TABLE 2
| ID | ABCD | AB | CD | 
|----+------+----+----|
| 0  |  71  | 21 | 50 |
| 1  |  86  | 53 | 33 |
| 2  |  72  | 35 | 37 |
| 3  |  125 | 80 | 45 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest creating a view here:

```
CREATE VIEW yourView AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        A + B + C + D AS ABCD,
        A + B AS AB,
        C + D AS CD
    FROM TABLE_1
)
```

It is probably not an efficient solution to try to actually maintain these data in an actual materialized table, because the data is derived.

Comment: Was just in the process of creating a fiddle for that so you might as well have it https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fibYRKxawCFZ6kXszMRpRr/0

Comment: Thank you. Do you believe this is a duplicate question? If not, should I revise my title in any way to reach others that may have a similar question?

Comment: I didn't feel it was an exact duplicate, no.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a `VIEW` is to add `VIRTUAL` [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to `Table1`. You can add them using an `ALTER TABLE` command:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD COLUMN ABCD INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (A+B+C+D) VIRTUAL,
ADD COLUMN AB INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (A+B) VIRTUAL,
ADD COLUMN CD INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (C+D) VIRTUAL;
```

The use of the `VIRTUAL` keyword means these values are computed when rows are read, rather than being stored in the table. Having done this, you can now

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

Output

```
ID  A   B   C   D   ABCD    AB  CD
0   11  10  39  11  71      21  50
1   32  21  21  12  86      53  33
2   12  23  24  13  72      35  37
3   45  35  31  14  125     80  45
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fibYRKxawCFZ6kXszMRpRr/1)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think that comment only applies to the version of `NDB` *if* you are using the `NDB` cluster engine. The code works fine on `db-fiddle` and they are not using it (`SELECT VERSION()` shows no `ndb-x.x.x` suffix). Also if you look at the comment on the MySQL5.5 manual, it just says "Generated columns are also supported by the NDB storage engine"

Comment: That's good to know +1.  MySQL's documentation is known for being buggy and open source.  If your code runs, then it runs.

Comment: Yours is probably still the more universal solution.